# DNS records file MX not working

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a DNS server setup using webmin, and I am having trouble getting the MX records to work. I just want to double check that my records file is setup correctly.

```
$ttl 38400
example.com.    IN  SOA ns1.example.com. 1055026205 (
            29
            1D
            1H
            1W
            3H )
example.        IN    A     123.456.7.890
www.example.com.    IN    CNAME example.com.
ns1.example.com.    IN    A     123.456.7.890
ns2.example.com.    IN    A     123.456.7.890
mail.example.com.   IN    A     123.456.7.890
example.com.        IN    NS    ns1.example.com.
example.com.        IN    NS    ns2.example.com.
mail.example.com.   IN    MX    10 example.com.
123.456.7.890.example.com.  IN  PTR example.com.
```

Comment: Is `example.        IN    A     123.456.7.890` a typo?

Answer (score 4):

You didn't really say how you intended to configure the mail service...

If your SMTP server is listening at `example.com` (`123.456.7.890`), then the config you included looks like a correct way to handle mail for domain `mail.example.com`, that is, for email addresses like `David@mail.example.com`.

I can only guess that you might want mail to work for the domain `example.com`, that is email addresses like `David@example.com`. In that case you would need an `MX` record on `example.com` itself.

By the way, in zone files it is conventional to list the `SOA` record first, then the `NS` records, then everything else. Also, your `PTR` record is meaningless. `PTR` records are used almost exclusively in reverse zones (under `in-addr.arpa` and `ip6.arpa`).